# Restrict the classes that may implement an interface

Tags: java, generics

Generally speaking, is it possible to restrict the classes that may implement an interface?

More specifically, can a generic interface `Foo<T>` restrict its implementations to descendants of `T`:

```
interface Foo<T> {}
class Baz extends Bar implements Foo<Bar> {} // desirable
class Baz extends Bar implements Foo<Qux> {} // undesirable
```

The context is that `Foo<Bar>` objects should be castable to `Bar` objects in a type-safe way.

Having exhausted all other sources of information, I already have a strong hunch that this isn't possible—but I would be delighted if someone could prove otherwise!

Comment: Does it need to be cast? Wouldn't a `T getT()` method be sufficient? An implementation could implement it as `return this;` if it happens to be of the correct type.

Comment: @Joachim: now I just feel silly! :) That'll do perfectly—thank you.  If you post as an answer, I can mark/rate it appropriately?

Comment: From JDK17 on you would seal the interface https://openjdk.org/jeps/409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ability to cast is not strictly necessary, then adding an additional method like this to your interface might suffice:

```
public T getT()
```

If most implementations actually extend `T`, they can simply `return this` as the implementation of that method.

Answer (score 3):

Following shows me a compilation error on line 7, so I assume this is what you want, right?

```
1 public interface Foo<T extends Bar> {}
2
3 public class Bar{}
4 public class Qux{}
5
6 class Baz extends Bar implements Foo<Bar> {}
7 class Baz2 extends Bar implements Foo<Qux> {}
```

Also, consider Joachim's advice (why cast, just use `T`). It is how generics were intended to be used.

Comment: Thanks mindas, but unfortunately not: I don't want to restrict the interface's type parameter—rather ensure that any implementing class follows the pattern of descending from the type parameter that it declares on the interface.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide some code illustrating this? Current edition doesn't make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could limit who can implement your interface is by controlling visibility of your interface using visiblity modifiers: public, protected, private or the default one (package).