# Restrict classes that can implement interface in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Before we start: I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040831/restrict-the-classes-that-may-implement-an-interface) and in my case that answer will not work.

So let's say I have:

```
interface Iface
class SuperClass (this one is from external library and can't be changed)
class SubClass extends SuperClass
class OtherClass
```

Is there a way to make it so that `Iface` can only be implemented by `SuperClass` and its subclasses? So in this case:

```
class SuperClass implements Iface - would be good if I could edit that class
class SubClass implements Iface   - good
class OtherClass implements Iface - bad
```

Side question: is that against OOP principles or is it a sign of bad code to do so?

Comment: If you end up to restrict the possible implementations of `Iface`, it could show that you try to use the _wrong_ tool to solve your problem.

Comment: @Spotted Well maybe I am. I just tried to restrict it to only classes that it makes sense for. Iterable makes sense for collections but doesn't make sense for integer or PrintWriter. In my case interface `Iface` only makes sense for subclasses of `SuperClass`, but I want to keep it an interface. If I make them classes, I can't use multiple inheritance. If instead of `Iface` I'd have `Iface1`, `Iface2` and `Iface3`, that would mean making 7 different classes and extending them instead of extending `SuperClass` and adding whatever interfaces are needed.

Comment: Of course it doesn't make sense for `PrintWriter` to implements `Iterable`. But does that had an impact on the visibility/accessibility to the `Iterable` interface ? Of course not, because everyone should be allowed to implement an interface as long as the contract is fullfilled (=an implementation for the interface's methods is provided).

Comment: So I just rely on common sense (and javadoc reading) of whoever uses that code later? Because the only thing keeping me from turning it into a class is that I need multiple inheritance.

Comment: If you want to restrict implementations (for whatever reason), using an interface won't provide you this guarantee (as it allows an unlimited number of possible implementations). With the context you provided, the best advice I can give you is to declare directly the methods in `SubClass` and mark all the methods either `abstract` or `final`.

Comment: From JDK17 on you would seal the interface https://openjdk.org/jeps/409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option I see is to make the interface package-private and implement it by public `SuperClass` which is located in the same package. This way the users of your package will be able to subclass the `SuperClass`, but not able to implement your interface directly. Note though that this way the interface itself becomes not very useful as nobody outside can even see it.

In general it seems that your problem can be solved just by removing the interface and replacing it everywhere with `SuperClass`.

Comment: It just occured to me that I didn't mention that I can't modify SuperClass because it's from an external lib. I'll edit question appropriately

Comment: Then do what Tagir wrote, but for the subclasses and not the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

I believe and referring [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html), A **public** interface cant be stopped from being inherited. An interface by definition is designed to work that way and we have access specifiers and stuffs in Java to make a Interface with lesser visibility. Would love to shown a way though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I absolutely agree with @Tagir's answer (and believe it should be accepted), to be fair one can make restrictions on what classes can implement what interfaces in *runtime* if he uses his own implementation of [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). Also, I think such a thing can be done in compile time if one builds his own [JVM-based](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/) language.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Java "Sealed" classes and interfaces were added to control, which classes can implement interfaces and classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html#GUID-0C709461-CC33-419A-82BF-61461336E65F

Preview was first presented in Java 15 and since Java 17 they are fully supported.