# make an interface only extendable by other interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Is it possible to restrict an interface so it can only be extended by other interfaces? For example:

I have 2 interfaces, Read and Write. Read contains methods for reading datastorage, write to write to datastorage. However I only want to make other interfaces able to extend these interfaces so classes can't implement them.

Comment: In one word: No!

Comment: There is no such restriction in java because it defeats the purpose of interfaces...

Comment: Found a similar question and a good answer :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007574/restrict-classes-that-can-implement-interface-in-java

Comment: Could you give more details why do you need this feature?