# Why isn't there a way for an interface to require implementing classes to reference their own type?

Tags: java, generics

Interfaces like `Comparable<>` use generics to establish which type a class is comparable to. In some cases, it may make sense to have one class comparable to another such as `A implements Comparable<B>`. But I'm working through a situation now where I would like the interface to specify that the return type is always the same as the type implementing the interface. That is to say, the type of `A.get()` should always be `A`.

My original attempt to force self-reference looked like:

```
interface Property<T extends Property<T>> {
    public T get();
}
```

This allows

```
class A implements Property<A> {
    public A get() { ... }
}
```

while preventing things like

```
class A implements Property<B> {
    public B get() { ... }
}
```

Unfortunately, it allows the following to compile:

```
class A implements Property<A> {
    public A get() { ... }
}
class B implements Property<A> {
    public A get() { ... }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040831/restrict-the-classes-that-may-implement-an-interface

Comment: Can I ask /why/ you want to do this? If a target expects `Property<A>` the implementing class shouldn't be of concern

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to force a subclass to narrow a return type on an inherited method based on the generic type parameter of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).  You cannot force `B` to have `get()` return `B`.  It's an object-oriented principle that a subclass can inherit a method without changing anything about it.

Sometimes I've wished for this feature -- a generic "relationship to self" type.  Here's how I would have the syntax.  The keyword "this" would represent this type - `A` in `A`, `B` in `B`.

```
public class A {
    public this get() {
       return this;  // Or another instance of this type
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    // "this" on get in A forces B to override "get"
    // to narrow the return type
    @Override
    public this get() {
       return this;
    }
}
```

But forcing `B` to override `getA()` goes against object-oriented principles.  The subclass should be free to inherit a method from a superclass as-is.